# Resources discussing best data SIM card in Morocco

Tags: cellphones, internet, morocco, mobile-operators

I will travel to Morocco soon and I am considering buying a SIM card. I am mainly looking for data, but if cost is similar, I might buy data+voice. Additional information like where to buy, is welcome.

I am looking for resources (websites or others) that compare operators in cost and network availability.

Prior to posting this question I googled for this subject. However, the results are either biased (they seem to be from sellers or interested parties) or old (< 2020), before the pandemic.

Comment: Probably look on the [prepaid data SIM wiki](https://prepaid-data-sim-card.fandom.com/wiki/Morocco).

Comment: @mlc maybe you can make that an answer. However, that was one of the resources I looked at, and that seem outdated.